# Optimal degree and C parameter in Polynomial SVM

Tags: classification, svm

Okay I know that there are a lot of posts out there about the C parameter in SVM, but I had a quick question about this.

In Polynomial SVM (Which I'll be coding in Python), I can set the parameters of "Degree", "C", and "Gamma". Now I read somewhere that in this case, my "Gamma" parameter need not be set/modified, and that the focus should be on finding the optimal "Degree" parameter. I wanted to confirm this statement. Should I go with finding the right combination to "Degree" and "C"? [or just "Degree"?]

Here, C is the Cost variable that acts as a tradeoff between how large you can have the minimum margin of the SVM to be, and how well you are able to correctly classify the points in your dataset.

Quick info about the dataset, there are about 10,000 data points (Before Training+Test split)and it's a binary classification problem. Also, setting degree to anything '7' and above takes a TON of time computationally.

Comment: Could you edit to include the expression you're talking about? On their own, parameter names like "C" don't mean anything.

Comment: No, you definitely need to optimize C. Also I feel that a 7th degree polynomial is too high. You don't need to go that far up.

Comment: @user20160 Sure sorry I edited it.